# How do I scrape this specific website? It requires a login, requires javascript and it's API isn't public

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, mechanicalsoup

First of I'd like to mention I'm still confused about how exactly website requests work, I know the basics like GET and POST requests, but not really how everything interacts with each other. I am trying to write a program for my younger brother to get notifications when a class starts, or if a class is cancelled. To achieve this I am trying to get the required data from the school website using python. It's illegal for the public to use their API, which makes things a lot harder. Without really knowing what to do I started just trying things. The website requires the student to login and thus, I tried to use GET and POST requests with mechanicalsoup, but that didn't work because it doesn't support by website required javascript. Afterwards I tried to use selenium, but that didn't work either because it can't find the form to input the user data.

I have been able to scrape data from other websites, (like reddit, for example) but this one just doesn't want to work. For info, the website is [this link](https://ozhw.magister.net). It's been 3 days just trying various things now so I'm lost xd.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out on this one

EDIT: Selenium Script used

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ozhw.magister.net")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("private")
```

Comment: `Afterwards I tried to use selenium, but that didn't work either because it can't find the form to input the user data.` What are you using to find this form? Their website appears to mark the username form input with `id=username`, which ought to be a reliable way to find it.

Comment: However, remember that Selenium operates in real-time.  There's going to be a delay between your request and the time the page is ready.  Add a `time.sleep` in there to let the page post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used the following line to find the form:
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("private")
(I edited the post as well to include the selenium script I used, if that helps)

Comment: @TimRoberts That worked. It's funny how I've been struggling with this a few days and the solution was so simple haha. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

*As Tim Roberts pointed out, the below method does not work for this use case. However, this strategy is good to know for other login problems you may encounter.*

<strike>Selenium is overkill for this</strike>. You just need to figure out the steps the browser is taking to get its future requests authorized.

**Discovery**

We need to find the

- Form structure for each step
- Authentication steps and their endpoints

1. Inspect the web page in your browser (right click then **inspect**).
2. Go to the **Network** tab of the inspection window
3. Submit the username
4. Look for the outgoing request in `Network` that contains the username. This should provide the form, endpoint, and other data that may be relevant to the request.
5. Given the username submission is separate from the password, it probably comes back with a token that you send alongside the password. You're going to need to figure this part out after getting a successful username request.

I see that the username submission contains a auth code, which may have its own process that you have to go through. With the site open refresh the page and you should see all of the requests sent from the browser to get that code (assuming that code is acquired separately).

**Python**

As you gain an understanding of what endpoints are doing the authentication, what data they require, and what they return, you can put each step into Python. A client/session will be important. I recommend [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) or [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do this.

Here is a skeleton of what you could fill out (may be incomplete, adjust as you must).

```py
import httpx


def visit_login_page(client, ...):
    # Fill this in with whatever you need
    return # response


def send_username(client, context, ...):
    # Fill this in with whatever you need
    return # response


def send_password(client, context, ...):
    # Fill this in with whatever you need
    return # response


with httpx.Client() as client:
    context = {}
    context["page_r"] = visit_login_page(client, ...)
    context["username_r"] = send_username(client, context, ...)
    context["password_r"] = send_password(client, context, ...)

    # If all went well, your client is now authenticated and can send requests to the protected pages
    # You may still have to send a token with each request
    ...
```

Comment: You seem to have taken a lot of time to write this, but your answer is completely wrong.  If you do View Source, you'll see that the page that is returned contains essentially no HTML at all.  It is entirely built by Javascript.  Thus, `requests` and `httpx` won't work, and `Selenium` is clearly not overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. After taking a harder look at the page, you are right that `selenium` is not overkill. It seems I underestimated "requires javascript". However, `requests` and `httpx` are not sidelined because there is no HTML. They don't work because the session token is generated using the Javascript and that token is submitted in the authentication requests. The pattern I provided applies to similar login problems, although not this one.